# Can there be two 'uvm_tlm_b_target_socket' and two corresponding 'b_transport' implementation in a single object?

Tags: uvm

I have a requirement where I need to have two `uvm_tlm_b_target_socket` in class as it going to receive transaction from two different agents. I need to process the data received from two sockets differently so I cannot have a single implementation of `b_transport` task. Is there anything equivalent for target socket to terminator of analysis ports were we can use `uvm_analysis_imp_decl` macro which allow us to have a different implementation of `write` function? In the class reference manual I could find this macro `uvm_blocking_transport_imp_decl` but couldn't find an example of how to use this.  In summary I am trying to do this

```
uvm_tlm_b_target_socket A;
umv_tlm_b_target_socket B;

// b_transport task implementation for socket "A"
task b_transport;

// b_transport task implementation for socket "B"
task b_transport;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the classical TLM2 sockets, there are also `*_transport_imps`. As far as I could tell, these do the same thing as sockets. You use the `*_decl` macro just like you use `uvm_analysis_imp_decl`:

```
class some_class;
  `uvm_blocking_transport_imp_decl(_a)
  `uvm_blocking_transport_imp_decl(_a)

  uvm_transport_imp_a A;
  umv_transport_imp_b B;

  task b_transport_a(...);
  task b_transport_b(...);
endclass
```

Comment: can `uvm_tlm_b_initiator_socket` connect to `uvm_transport_imp`?

Answer (score 1):

uvm_tlm_b_target_socket when instantiated needs to be provided two parameters.

1) base class where the implementation - b_transport resides

2) the other is the data item itself.

```
   uvm_tlm_b_target_socket #(receiver, data_item) A;
```

You can only have 1 transport_b function in your receiver class .
But you can use a wrapper class to connect the other functions in your receiver class to other target sockets.

```
typedef class receiver; // name of the parent class processing the transport call.

class connect_transport ; // does not need to be a component but if you need it can - extends uvm_component;
receiver m_parent; // parent class 
   function new(string name = "receiver", receiver parent = null);
        m_parent = parent; // connect the parent class 
   endfunction
   task b_transport(data_item data, uvm_tlm_time delay);
        // transport_b for B.
        m_parent.b_transport_b(data,delay); // call the function in the parent class.
   endtask
endclass
```

in the receiver class

```
class receiver  extends umm_component ; 
`uvm_component_utils(receiver)
    connect_transport    c1;

.....
   uvm_tlm_b_target_socket #(receiver, data_item) A; // connects to the local b_transport function 
   uvm_tlm_b_target_socket #(connect_transport, data_item) B; // connect to the wrapper class

  function new(string name = "receiver", uvm_component parent = null);
      super.new(name, parent);
      A = new("A", this);
      c1 = new ("c1",this); // create the connecting class 
      B = new("B", this,c1); // connect the target socket to the connecting class

  endfunction

  //for socket B
  task b_transport_b(data_item data, uvm_tlm_time delay);
  ......
  end task

  // will be connected to A socket.
  task b_transport(data_item data, uvm_tlm_time delay);
  ......
  end task 
endclass
```

You can wrap this into a macro , and have an _imp_decl kind of implementation.
 You could also implement the check directly in the connect_transport.